# EAV модель VS виртуальная генерация столбцов в MySQL через JSON

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, проектирование

Недавно на хабре появилась [любопытная для меня статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/348854/), после прочтения которой и возник подобный вопрос. Насколько адекватной является замена стандартной EAV модели архитектуры БД на БД с JSON данными и динамически генерируемыми столбцами?

Лично мне кажется, что использование JSON в том ключе, как описано в статье, является более удобным для разработки и поддержки, однако под адекватностью я имею ввиду оптимизацию. Хочется узнать мнение опытных специалистов в Базах Данных и людей, которые уже сталкивались с подобной архитектурой

Comment: А чем модель с JSON и динамически генерируемыми столбцами отличается от простой таблицы с такими столбцами ? по хорошему ни чем. EAV используется когда вам надо заложить возможность добавлять столбцы, не меняя код приложения. И при этом обеспечить поиск по ним. добавление, хоть и виртуальных, колонок в таблицу в любом случае приводит к необходимости указывать эти колонки в запросе. что автоматически приводит нас к обычной плоской таблице и необходимости перечисления всех колонок в запросе (что часто и не плохо, но причем тут тогда EAV).

Comment: Если уж работать с JSON то imho стоит брать более адекватные БД, вроде postgresql, где вы можете построить специальный индекс прямо на json поле и далее работать с ним прямо json операторами, а не указывая некие виртуальные колонки